# A function which is continuous and discontinuous on a dense set.

Tags: real-analysis

Can an unbounded function in $R$ both continuous  a dense set of points and discontinuous on a dense set of points?

I guess it is impossible since at least one discontinuity means the function is not continuous so  I am looking for an example but can not find it.

Comment: Do you know of a function that is continuous at the irrational points, and discontinuous at the rational points?

Comment: Hint: If you have a function $f$ such that $0<f<1$, $f$ is continuous on a dense set and discontinuous on another dense such that $f$ takes values arbitrarily close to $0$ then $\frac 1 f$ would be an example.

Comment: There are many such functions. One very common example is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275430/epsilon-delta-proof-that-f-is-continuous-for-x-notin-mathbb-q-but-isn). My answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68326/popcorn-function) generalizes that example. There is a very different example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69317/construct-a-monotone-function-which-has-countably-many-discontinuities).