# What can discontinuities for a function $f:{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ be?

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set of continuity points of a real function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67620/set-of-continuity-points-of-a-real-function)

Consider an function $f:{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ and the standard topology. Suppose that $S\subset{\mathbb R}$ is the set of *all* the discontinuities of $f$. Here are my **questions**:

- For any $S\subset{\mathbb R}$, can we *always* find an $f:{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$, such that $S$ is the set of *all* the discontinuities of $f$?
- If the answer to the question above is NO, then what kinds of $S\subset{\mathbb R}$ generally can be?

I found several such $S\subset{\mathbb R}$:

- $S = \emptyset:\qquad f(x) = x$
- $S = {\mathbb R}$:
  $$
  f(x) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
      0, &  x\in{\mathbb Q}~; \\
      1, &  x\in{\mathbb R}\setminus{\mathbb Q}~.
    \end{array}
  \right.
  $$
- etc.

But I still don't have any idea how to answer the questions.

Comment: $S$ is the set of discontinuity of a real function if and only if it is an $F_\sigma$ (countable union of closed sets). See the thread above.

Comment: @t.b.: Ah, I didn't notice that question. Thanks for you answer and closing the duplicate question. `:-)`