# No function that is continuous at all rational points and discontinuous at irrational points.

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set of continuity points of a real function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67620/set-of-continuity-points-of-a-real-function)

I think I saw somewhere(but I'm not sure) that there is no function $g$ on $[0,1]$ that is continuous at all rational points and discontinuous at all irrational points. Please, is this true? If yes how can I show it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, what you remember is true.
The set of discontinuities of $g$ is a $F_\sigma$, a denumerable union of closed subsets of $[0,1]$, and the irrationals are not such a union because of Baire's theorem.

**Edit**
Let me show in detail (as an answer to Linda's question in the comments) why $[0,1]\setminus \mathbb Q$ is not a union $\bigcup F_n$ of countably many closed subsets $F_n\subset [0,1]$.
First note that each $F_n$ would have empty interior since else it would contain some rational numbers.
  On the other hand $[0,1]\cap \mathbb Q=\bigcup G_n$ with $G_n=\lbrace q_n\rbrace $,  with the $q_n$  some enumeration of $\mathbb Q$.
So we would have a presentation $[0,1]=(\bigcup F_n)\bigcup (\bigcup G_n)$ of the complete metric space $[0,1] $ as a denumerable union of closed sets without interior. 
Baire's theorem says that this is impossible.

Comment: Ah. I had forgotten this tidbit. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Thanks. What will happen if the irrationals are a union of closed subsets of [0,1]?

Comment: Well, the irrationals in $[0,1]$ *are* a union of closed subsets of $[0,1]$--namely a union of singletons--but it isn't a countable union, as your edit points out.

Comment: Dear Linda, the point is that it is  not such a *denumerable*  union! I have written an edit to spell that out. (Thanks to @Cameron who judiciously remarks that it *is* a union, albeit a non-denumerable one)