# Points at which function is continuous is countable intersection of open sets

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f$ be a real-valued function defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Show that the set of points at which $f$ is continuous is a countable intersection of open sets.

Not sure where to start on this one... what would be the open sets?

Comment: Also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/67620/264 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/211511/264

Comment: Where to start? How about the definition of continuity?