# Set of discontinuous points

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f$ is function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let be the set $\mathbf{A}$ that contains all the discontinuous points of $f$.Is  $\mathbf{A}$ Borel Measureable?

Comment: What do you know about the set of continuity points?

Comment: you know nothing. You only know that $f$ is a random function and $\mathbf{A}$ is the set of discontinuous points of $f$.

Comment: Huh? (also, are you paying your ISP by the amount of characters you type? If not, please write `you` instead of `u`; if yes, then this is 2013 and surely you can find a better deal.)

Comment: @Asaf Karagila. You know nothing. You only know that $f$ is a random function and$\mathbf{A}$ is the set of discontinuous points of $f$. But i think you can assume there is a set of continious point.

Comment: An empty set of continuity points is still a set. I was trying to point out the fact that the set of continuity points is always Borel, so its complement must be Borel too.

Comment: The set of discontinuity is the complement of the set of continuity points. So to solve your question it, suffices to show that the set of continuity points is Borel.

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211511/set-of-points-of-continuity-are-g-delta), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138072/how-to-show-that-the-set-of-points-of-continuity-is-a-g-delta). Other questions listed among linked posts there can be also interesting for you.

Answer (score 10):

The set of point of continuity is a $G_\delta$ set. So the points of discontinuity is $F_\sigma$. $F_\sigma$ sets are certainly Borel.

---

To see this: Let $C$ be the set of points of continuity of $f$. Define $\text{osc}_f(x) = \inf \{\text{diam}(f(U)) : x \in U \text{ and } U \text{ is open }\}$. Note $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if $\text{osc}_f(x) = 0$. Show that for each $\epsilon$, the set $E_\epsilon = \{x : \text{osc}_f(x) < \epsilon\}$ is open. Then $C = \{x : \text{osc}_f(x) = 0\} = \bigcap_n E_{\frac{1}{n}}$. So what you called $A = \mathbb{R} - C$ is $F_\sigma$.

---

The oscillation is just how small the image an open set containing $x$ can be made. Suppose $f$ is continuous at $x$, then for all $\epsilon$, there exists a $\delta$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x - y| < \delta$. This means that $\operatorname{diam}((x - \delta, x + \delta)) < 2\epsilon$ (use triangle inequality). So $\operatorname{osc}_f(x) < 2\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, $\operatorname{osc}_f(x) = 0$. Conversely suppose $\operatorname{osc}_f(x) = 0$. Then for all $\epsilon$, there exist an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that $|f(a)  - f(b)| < \epsilon$ if $a,b \in U$. Choose $\delta$ such that $(x - \delta, x + \delta) \subseteq U$. Then if $|x - y| < \delta$, $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$. So $f$ is continuous.

Comment: can u explain in words what that osc means? and why is osc=0 iff f continious.

Comment: @user95525 I added some more explanation to the answer.

Comment: But how do i show that C is Borel?

Comment: @user95525 I showed above that $C$ is $G_\delta$, which means it is a countable intersection of open sets. $G_\delta$ sets are Borel. You do know that the collection of Borel sets contain the open sets and are closed under complements and countable intersection?

Comment: Im following the course Measure theory and i find it very difficult. I forgot that the collection of Borel sets contain the open sets and are closed under complements and countable intersection.

Comment: @user95525 You can find some basic things about oscillation of a function on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation_%28mathematics%29). Maybe that can help you, too.

Comment: @William can you please explain why is $E_\epsilon = \{x : \text{osc}_f(x) < \epsilon\}$ open ? I know that inverse image of an open set is open for continuous function, but here I think we don't know whether $\text{osc}_f(x)$ is continuous or not.

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal In metric spaces, a set is open if every point in the set has an open ball contained in the set. Use this definition to prove the set is open.

Comment: @William could you please show how it is done, I'm not able to do it. Moreover if we show it is true for all $\epsilon$ then won't this imply that $\text{osc}_f$ is continuous ? which is not true in general!

Comment: @William thanks for the answer. A small typo. It was writtten as $\operatorname{diam}((x - \delta, x + \delta)) < 2\epsilon$ but should be $\operatorname{diam}(f(x - \delta, x + \delta)) < 2\epsilon$.