# Let $f$ be a real valued function on $\mathbb{R}$, the set of points at which $f$ is continuous is a $G_\delta$ set

Tags: real-analysis

First, I found two other posts of people who asked this question.

[How to show that the set of points of continuity is a $G_{\delta}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138072/how-to-show-that-the-set-of-points-of-continuity-is-a-g-delta)

[Set of points of continuity are $G_{\delta}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211511/set-of-points-of-continuity-are-g-delta)

However, because of the way that I'm attempting to solve it, I didn't find these threads to be helpful.

The question is to show that

Let $f$ be a real valued function on $\mathbb{R}$, the set of points at which $f$ is continuous is a $G_\delta$ set.

Note that a $G_{\delta}$ set is a the intersection of a countable collection of open sets.

My solution idea:

We know that for a set $E$ of real numbers, $f$ is continuous on $E$ if and only if for each open set $O$ in the range of the function, $f^{-1}(O) = E \cap U$ where $U$ is an open set$.

So denote the set of points at which $f$ is continuous by $E$. Then for each open set $O_i$ in the range of $f$, we have $f^{-1}(O_i) = E \cap U_i$.

Now maybe I could use the fact that the $O_i$ in the range must be countable?

I feel like I'm close, but I'm stuck at this point. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "the $O_i$ in the range must be countable"?

Comment: Note that having the restriction of $f$ to $E$ being continuous is a weaker condition than having $f$ with domain $\mathbb R$ be continuous at each point in $E$, so it doesn't seem like this approach will work.  This is because being continuous at $x\in\mathbb R$ requires good behavior of the function near $x$, including at points that might not be in $E$.

Comment: Each open set $O_i$ in the range must contain a rational number and we can put the rational numbers in one to one correspondence with $\mathbb{N}$ so we can put the open intervals in the range in one to one correspondence with $\mathbb{N}$. Maybe I should have said there is a countable number of disjoint open intervals in the range?

Comment: There are an uncountable number of open intervals in $\mathbb R$. What are these disjoint intervals?  Perhaps you are thinking of the fact that an open set in $\mathbb R$ is a countable disjoint union of open intervals, but you are not restricting to one open set, but taking an arbitrary open set, of which there are uncountably many.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're saying. Thank you. I will try another approach.