# Does any example of a function continuous at rationals and discontinuous at irrationals exist?

Tags: real-analysis

Does any example of this particular type of function, stated below exist?          f:$R\to R$ is continuous at every rational numbers and discontinuous at every irrational points. I can't find any example. If there does not exist any such function then why?

Comment: The set of continuity points is a $G_{\delta}$ set, countable intersection of open sets, rationals aren't.

Comment: As a reference to that fact:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138072/how-to-show-that-the-set-of-points-of-continuity-is-a-g-delta

Comment: is the set of irrational numbers $G_\delta$ set?

Comment: Yes.  They are the intersection of $\{\mathbb R - q_i\}$ where the $q_i's$ list the rationals.

Comment: By the way, that proves that $\mathbb Q$ is not $G_{\delta}$, for it were the countable intersection of open sets $O_i$ then we could intersect these with the open sets $\{\mathbb R - q_i\}$ to get $\emptyset$ as a countable intersection of dense open sets, in violation of the Baire category theorem.

Comment: The link suggested by @MiguelAtencia covers all this very clearly.