# The set of points where a function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is discontinuous is Lebesgue measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, continuity

Prove that the set of points where a function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is discontinuous is   Lebesgue measurable.

Lebesgue measure of set $A$ means that for any set $S\in\mathbb R,$ $m^*(S)=m^*(A\cap S)+m^*(A^c\cap S)$.

I think I should start with the definition of the negation of continuous function,

$\exists\epsilon>0,\forall\delta>0,\exists x\in D_f:\vert x-x_0\vert<\delta$ and $\vert f(x)-f(x_0)\vert\ge\epsilon$

and then should I see that $(x_0+\delta,x_0-\delta)$ is Lebesgue measure ?

Am I correct?

Comment: You should probably start by getting the negation correct. :) And, of course any open interval is Lebesgue-measurable, so that's certainly not the point.

Comment: @TedShifrin I confused things..I edited.

Comment: See appendix M10 of Patrick Billingsley's "Convergence of Probability Measures" for a proof.

Comment: @DonThousand $f$ is an arbitrary function.

Comment: See also: [How to show that the set of points of continuity is a $G_{\delta}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/138072).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you. What's $G_\delta$ ? And how is this related to the solution of my exercise?

Comment: Wikipedia: [Gδ set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_set): A countable intersection of open sets. Every [Borel measurable set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set) is Lebesgue measurable. (In short, if you know that countable intersection of measurable sets is measurable and that every open set is measurable, you immediately get that any $G_\delta$-set is measurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if nothing is known about $f$ except that it maps $\mathbb R$ into itself you can proceed as follows: let $\omega(x) =\lim_{\delta \to 0} \sup \{|f(x)-f(y)|: |y-x|\ \leq \delta \}$. You can verify that  $\{x:\omega (x) <t\}$ is open for each real number $t$. Hence $\omega$ is a Borel measurable function. Now verify that $f$ is continuous at $x$ iff $\omega (x)=0$. So the points of discontinuity form a Borel set. No need to worry about Lebesgue measurability.

Comment: Is the $a$ from $\{x:\omega (x) <a\}$ the $a$ of the domain ?

Comment: @Isa Sorry, I have changed it to $t$.

Comment: thank you Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: I wasn't able to show it following this approach. I instead followed Folland's approach in the exercise proving part (b) of Theorem 2.28. In particular I got stuck at showing $\{x: \omega(x) < t\}$ is open in $[a,b]$. How do you show that?