# Rationals can be the set of continuity of a function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

Most of the functions that I have seen have their discontinuities on rationals and continuities on irrationals!

I am wondering if there is any exampe of some function whose continuities are rationals? Or is other words

> The set of continuities of a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ can be $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: No, the set of points of continuity of a function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is always a $G_\delta$ set and $\Bbb Q$ isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the set of points of continuity of a function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is always a $G_\delta$ set and $\Bbb Q$ isn't.

For the first claim see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138072/how-to-show-that-the-set-of-points-of-continuity-is-a-g-delta).

For the second claim see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69451/how-to-show-that-mathbbq-is-not-g-delta)