# Continuous only at rational pts

Tags: analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set of continuity points of a real function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67620/set-of-continuity-points-of-a-real-function)

I'm studying continuous in analysis class.
I have a question. That's simple!

Is there a function that is continuous only at rational points?

I have no idea for find that. If you know, plz some hint.
thanks!

Comment: See [Set of continuity points of a real function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67620/set-of-continuity-points-of-a-real-function) and other questions linked from there.

Comment: There is no such function. For any function from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the set of discontinuities form an $F_{\sigma}$ set. The set $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ is not an $F_{\sigma}$ set.

Comment: Oh It's pretty clear. Thanks