# Is there a function that is contiunous at all the rationals, and discontinuous at all the irrationals?

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set of continuity points of a real function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67620/set-of-continuity-points-of-a-real-function)

Motivated by the examples of the Dirichlet's no-where continuous function and [Thomae's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function), we know that a function can have discontinuities at the reals, or at the rationals. My question is whether the set of discontinuities can actually be at the irrationals only. [Froda's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Froda%27s_theorem) tells us that such a function cannot be monotone, so that cuts down on the search. Are there other obstructions? Can we exhibit such a function?

Comment: The set of points of continuity of a function is a countable intersection of open sets. $\Bbb Q$ is not such a set.

Comment: Yes, I should have searched harder. Thanks all for the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the first wikipedia page linked in your question, there is :

> A natural followup question one might ask is if there is a function which is continuous on the rational numbers and discontinuous on the irrational numbers. This turns out to be impossible; the set of discontinuities of any function must be an $F_\sigma$ set. If such a function existed, then the irrationals would be an $F_\sigma$ set and hence, as they don't contain an interval, would also be a meager set. It would follow that the real numbers, being a union of the irrationals and the rationals (which is evidently meager), would also be a meager set. This would contradict the Baire category theorem.