# Is every $G_\delta$ set the set of continuity points of some function $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

I can prove that given a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$, where $X,Y$ are metric spaces, the set $A \subseteq X$ of points on which $f$ is continuous, is $G_{\delta}$.

(Take $U_n = \bigcup_{y \in Im(f)} f^{-1}(B_{\frac{1}{n}}(y))$ and $V= \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}U_n$, and $V$ is $G_\delta$).

My question is: Is the converse direction true? Is it true that, given a $G_\delta$ set $A \subseteq X$, there exists a metric space $Y$, and a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$, such that, the set of points on which $f$ is continuous is $A$?

Thank you!
Shir

Comment: For $Y=\Bbb R$, see Pete L. Clark's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67620/set-of-continuity-points-of-a-real-function?lq=1).

Comment: Yes. See Theorem 2.1 on page 2 of in here: http://www.artsci.kyushu-u.ac.jp/~ssaito/eng/maths/Gdelta.pdf In fact, every dense $G_\delta\subset\mathbb R$ is also the set of continuity of a derivative of a differentiable function!

Comment: See in my [20 December 2006 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5447961), especially my comments in the section titled *PROOFS OF 2'* (note the prime ' on two 2).

Comment: I will have a look. Thank you!

Comment: Regarding the dupe closure:  [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/67626/468350) addresses the question which is posed here (see the third point).