# Any union of a countable number of closed sets is a set of discontinuity points of some function

Tags: calculus

I am following [Calculus lectures on YT](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLcsjsqLLSfNDuleTFinPo1WY3V4EesuLO) (in Russian) and stumbled upon the following statement that was left without proof --

> Any union of a countable number of closed sets is a set of discontinuity points of some function

I would appreciate it if someone can show how a strategy for proving this statement.

This statement comes right after the lecturer shows that number of discontinuity points of a monotone function is at most countable.

Comment: my translation might be off, apologies for that. I am trying to say that number of sets in the union is countable. This seems to be a weaker version of the theorem above https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3003058/any-countable-set-of-real-numbers-is-set-of-discontinuities-of-some-monotone-fun (unless I missed your point)

Comment: Okay, I thought it might be a confusion with [Froda's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Froda%27s_theorem), that the number of discontinuity points of a *monotone* function is at most countable.

Comment: It's fairly well known that any $F_{\sigma}$ set can be a discontinuity set for some function. See [Set of continuity points of a real function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/67620/13130) and [Is every $G_\delta$ set the set of continuity points of some function $f$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/632652/13130) Under PROOFS OF 2' in this [20 December 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/JSZiDgWxlPk/m/jolpTO7A2wUJ) I give about 20 references (books and papers) for this result. **(continued)**

Comment: FYI, this was first proved for functions $f:{\mathbb R} \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ by William H. Young in 1903 and Henri Lebesgue in 1904 (independently), extended to functions $f:{\mathbb R}^n \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ by William H. Young in 1905. I believe the first metric space version appears on pp. 193-194 of [Hans Hahn's 1932 book](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183496919).

Comment: @hardmath: Regarding Froda's theorem, see [B. S. Thomson's](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=bR0NFQgAAAAJ) answer to [Proof of Froda's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1500557/13130).