# Does there exist a function that is continuous at every rational point and discontinuous at every irrational point? And vice versa?

Tags: functions, continuity, examples-counterexamples, irrational-numbers

Actually there are 2 questions, but they are closely related.
Does it exist a function that is:

1. Continuous  at every rational point and discontinuous at every irrational point?
2. Continuous  at every irrational point and discontinuous at every rational point?

Comment: No, for the reason that $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{R}$ and also $\bar{\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Yes for continuous only at the irrationals, no for continuous only at the rationals. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gδ_set where all is explained.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma your link is broken

Comment: @KBusc The $\delta$ symbol behaves weird in links, apparently.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma try this one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_set

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054922

Answer (score 5):

For part 2, let $f(p/q)=1/q$ for rational points $p/q$ (in reduced form) and $f(x)=0$ for irrational $x$.

Answer (score 3):

For first part there does not exist  any function
Because f is discontinuous on only F-sigma set. F-sigma set is defined as the set which can be written as countable union of closed set.

Comment: Can you clear why this happens?

Comment: @Ppp See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/67626/1128456

Answer (score 0):

The set of discontinuities of any real function must be the countable union of closed sets.

The rationals, Q, is such a set, and so your Case #2 does exist (and should be easily Googled).  But the irrationals are not the countable collection of closed sets, so your Case #1 does not exist.