# Function continuous at irrationals and discontinuous at rationals

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

Q: Given the function $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$, where $f_n(x)=
     \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       0;   \;\;if  \;x< r_n \\
       \displaystyle \frac{1}{2^n}; x\geq r_n
     \end{array}
   \right.
  $

Here $r_n$ is an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$.
Show that $f(x)$ is contionuous at irrationals and discontinuous at rationals.

Here is my work. I proved that each $f_n(x)$ is continuous at irrationals. But now stuck in proving $f(x)$ continuous at irrationals. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I asked a bit similar question yesterday: [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054922/about-the-continuity-of-fx-undersetq-k-leq-x-sum-k-in-mathbbn-2). The answer there might help you.