# The derivative of a discrete distribution function is zero a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $\{q_n\}$ is an arbitrary enumeration of all rationals, and $$F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{2^n}\mathbf 1_{\{q_n\le x\}}$$  Then $F$ is a discrete distribution function with countable jump discontinuities (that are in $\mathbb Q$), but is continuous on $\mathbb {R\setminus Q}$, as shown in [About the continuity of the function $f(x) = \sum\limits_k2^{-k}\mathbf 1_{q_k \leq x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1054922/235690).

My question is: Is $F'(x)=0$ for every $x\notin \mathbb Q$?  If so, how do we prove it?

Comment: Please do not modify significantly your post (whether its title or its body) after you received answers. Additionally, in the present case, your edited title was difficult to understand. Two reasons to revert your unfortunate edit.

Comment: @Did Thanks for the pointers!  Will do.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily. Assume for example that $$\pi<q_{2n}<\pi+5^{-n}$$ for every $n$ (note that enumerations with this property do exist since the subsequence $(q_{2n+1})$ is free), then $$F(\pi+5^{-n})>F(\pi)+4^{-n}$$ hence $$\frac{F(\pi+5^{-n})-F(\pi)}{5^{-n}}>\left(\frac54\right)^n$$ which implies $$\lim_{x\to0,x>0}\frac{F(\pi+x)-F(\pi)}x=+\infty$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the simple counter-example!  But is the title of the question true, though?  I.e. Is $F'(x)=0$ a.e.?

Comment: If *other question* then *other post*.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Why not reread the definition of **limit** and ponder it seriously?

Comment: What I meant was, there's no derivative, but you last step for lim x->0, x>0, should only be  lim x->0, x=5^-n. On other sequences, we could have a different limit. No?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. A very small argument based on the monotonicity of $F$ allows to pass from the limit along the sequence $5^{-n}$ to the limit when $x\to0$, $x>0$. Anyway, that the limit along the sequence $5^{-n}$ is $+\infty$ suffices to conclude that $F'(x)=0$ does not hold.