# A follow-up question on "The derivative of a discrete distribution function is zero a.e.?"

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

This is a follow-up question to [The derivative of a discrete distribution function is zero a.e.?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2437465/235690), where a counter example shows that the derivative isn't necessarily zero where  $F$ (the d.f.) is continuous.  But the question remains: is the derivative of a discrete distribution function $F$ necessarily zero a.e.?  The answer is clearly yes, if $F$ has finite discontinuities.  But it's not clear to me if this is true when $F$ has countably infinite discontinuities.

For example, consider the same discrete d.f. $F$, i.e. suppose $\{q_n\}$ is an arbitrary enumeration of all rationals, and $$F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{2^n}\mathbf 1_{\{q_n\le x\}}.$$

Is $F'=0$ almost everywhere?  I'd appreciate any pointers.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: The answer appears to be yes: see https://eudml.org/doc/210892

Comment: @Bungo Thanks a lot for the reference!