# Function continuous on every rational points but discontinuous on irrational points

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples

Give an example of function which is continuous on every rational points and discontinuous on irrational points?

Comment: Good luck with this one! :)

Comment: see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/993770/does-there-exist-a-function-that-is-continuous-at-every-rational-point-and-disco