# the set of continuity points of $f$ are the set of algebraic numbers in $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

I have a following question in my mind regarding the set of continuity of points of $f$:

Does there exist a real valued function on $[0,1]$ such that the set of continuity points of $f$ are the set of algebraic numbers in $[0,1]$?

Thank You.

Comment: See [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math/oMfQxIVsQEo) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67620/set-of-continuity-points-of-a-real-function).

Comment: Nope: this is because algebraic numbers are not a $G_{\delta}$ set.