# Is there any function continuous only at rationals?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If I define a constant function on domain of rationals, then is it the right chosen function to be continuous at rationals?
Also is there any function with Domain of reals which is continuous on rationals?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67620/set-of-continuity-points-of-a-real-function have a look.

Comment: This question has been asked many times on this site...the duplicate I linked to is itself a duplicate.

Comment: This question is now marked as a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate! I've never seen that happen before.

Comment: Do you know Baire's category theorem?